# How to lower down output power of low power ultrasonic transducer?

Tags: transducer

I'm currently using a low power ultrasonic transducer for micro machining on ceramic. Kindly refer below for the spec of the low power ultrasonic transducer,

- Output Power =  max 2.0W (can be adjusted to 50%, which is 1.0W)
- Frequency = 65 kHZ

Current issues:

- If tighten the M4 thread with screw, the vibration transmit to the ceramic is not consistent.
- If loosen the M4 thread with screw, the vibration is too strong causing grinding pin to jump out.

May I know is it a way to lower down the output power (below 1.0W) or lower down peak to peak displacement?

[image: Photo of ultrasonic transducer]

[image: Diagram of mounted ultrasonic transducer]

[image: Diagram of operation]

Comment: What prevents you from adjusting the power below 50% (1W)?

Comment: The ultrasonic transducer is connected to an ultrasonic generator that has limited adjustment options. The generator can be set to either 0% to 50% power output (1W) or 100% power output (2W), without any intermediate options such as 25%.

Comment: You probably need to take a look at the datasheet for your transducer to see what its impedance is at 65kHz, then choose a similar-valued resistor to put in series with it,